# Can't connect to printer "Unable to locate printer "877725000000.local"."

Tags: cups, printer

I'm using Linux Mint 20.1, trying to connect to my printer over a WiFi network.  I found instructions to install CUPS from the terminal and create the printer interface.  However, when I try to print a test page from CUPS using this printer, I get the error "Unable to locate printer "877725000000.local"."  I also cannot print any documents directly.  The printer is on and works when accessed from a Windows machine.

I found the following issue which seems similar.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187966/cups-cant-add-printer-unable-to-locate-printer-web-interface

However I don't understand the answer given. I'm not an administrator and don't know how the backend of Linux works (just using Mint on my personal PC to stick to open source stuff, so I really don't have any training in how to use this stuff).  Through CUPS I found the configuration file:

```
LogLevel warn
PageLogFormat
MaxLogSize 0
Listen localhost:631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
Browsing Off
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
DefaultAuthType Basic
WebInterface Yes
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
<Location /admin/log>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
<Policy default>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
<Policy authenticated>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
<Policy kerberos>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Negotiate
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Negotiate
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Negotiate
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
```

This seems like the useful part of printing out `> avahi-browse --all -t -r`.

```
+ enp0s31f6 IPv4 Canon MG7100 series                           Web Site             local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv4 Canon MG7100 series                           _canon-bjnp1._tcp    local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv4 Canon MG7100 series                           _scanner._tcp        local
= enp0s31f6 IPv4 Canon MG7100 series                           UNIX Printer         local
   hostname = [877725000000.local]
   address = [###hidden###]
   port = [515]
   txt = ["Fax=F" "Scan=T" "Duplex=T" "Color=T" "UUID=00000000-0000-1000-8000-F48139877725" "mac=F4:81:39:87:77:25" "usb_MDL=MG7100 series" "usb_MFG=Canon" "adminurl=http://877725000000.local." "note=" "pdl=application/octet-stream" "product=(Canon MG7100 series)" "ty=Canon MG7100 series" "priority=60" "qtotal=1" "rp=auto" "txtvers=1"]
= enp0s31f6 IPv4 Canon MG7100 series                           Internet Printer     local
   hostname = [877725000000.local]
   address = [###hidden###]
   port = [631]
   txt = ["print-wfds=T" "PaperMax=legal-A4" "kind=document,envelope,photo" "Fax=F" "Scan=T" "Duplex=T" "Color=T" "UUID=00000000-0000-1000-8000-F48139877725" "mac=F4:81:39:87:77:25" "URF=V1.4,CP1,PQ4-5,RS600,SRGB24,W8,OB9,OFU0,DM3,IS20-21" "usb_CMD=URF" "usb_MDL=MG7100 series" "usb_MFG=Canon" "adminurl=http://877725000000.local./index.html?PAGE_AAP" "note=" "pdl=application/octet-stream,image/urf,image/jpeg,image/pwg-raster" "product=(Canon MG7100 series)" "ty=Canon MG7100 series" "priority=15" "qtotal=1" "rp=ipp/print" "txtvers=1"]
= enp0s31f6 IPv4 Canon MG7100 series                           Web Site             local
   hostname = [877725000000.local]
   address = [###hidden###]
   port = [80]
   txt = ["mac=F4:81:39:87:77:25" "txtvers=1"]
= enp0s31f6 IPv4 Canon MG7100 series                           _canon-bjnp1._tcp    local
   hostname = [877725000000.local]
   address = [###hidden###]
   port = [8611]
   txt = ["mac=F4:81:39:87:77:25" "note=" "priority=20" "txtvers=1"]
= enp0s31f6 IPv4 Canon MG7100 series                           _scanner._tcp        local
   hostname = [877725000000.local]
   address = [###hidden###]
   port = [8612]
   txt = ["scannerAvailable=1" "UUID=00000000-0000-1000-8000-F48139877725" "mac=F4:81:39:87:77:25" "mdl=MG7100 series" "mfg=Canon" "adminurl=http://877725000000.local." "ty=Canon MG7100 series" "txtvers=1"]
```

And here are screen shots from CUPS.

[image: CUPS shot 1]

[image: CUPS shot 2]

Answer (score 2):

Arch user here, I am adding this response in case someone finds it useful (even if you don't use arch) because it took me a while to find a solution. So:

1. Install nss-mdns using your package manager
2. Start/restart avahi-daemon.service
3. Replace the hosts line in /etc/nsswitch.conf with hosts: mymachines mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns

This fixed the issue for me!

Comment: This is right, but you need to restart cups.service.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look on https://openprinting.org/printers, and could not find that printer model listed. While that's not a death sentence, it's usually not a good sign. I would guess you need a Linux driver for it.

I found a possible driver at https://th.canon/en/support/0100551102 .

I don't know if this will help, but it's worth a try.

You didn't say what distro you're using, but if it's not one that uses rpm packages, you can install the `alien` command which can convert the package to other formats such as the Debian deb format. You would then install it using the `sudo dpkg -i converted-file-name.deb` command if it's a deb and for good measure, run `sudo apt-get install -f` afterward to find and, hopefully, clean up any dependencies or other issues caused by directly installing the package.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm using Linux Mint 20.1, I'll edit the question to include that. And I'll write here what happened just in case anyone in the future finds it useful.  I converted the rpm files to deb using `alien`.  I wasn't sure which ones so I basically did it to all of them and installed them all.  (Probably the x86-64 stuff is what I need but figured it couldn't hurt to try the others while I'm at it.)  Anyway, then installed them, installation went fine, and with `sudo apt-get install -f` there were no other dependencies that it needed.

Comment: However, when I try to configure the printer, it tries to find the drivers and even seems like it finds the drivers.  But then gives an error `server-error-internal-error` which I have no idea how to interpret, but I'm guessing it means the drivers didn't work.  So I'm probably just going to just use the Windows computer for printing jobs.

Comment: ... you know, come to think of it, ... I recently moved.  Before the move, my computer could print to the printer over the wifi network.  Now it can't.  What changed?  ... I think the main change is that we're now using AT&T's new fiber connection.  I wonder if that has to do with how the computer connects over the network.

Comment: Physically connect the printer, it might make it essier to configure. Wordt case, you could get a minimal Windows computer, attach the printer to it and then share it as a network printer. Also search the web for canon mg7100 linux driver. There are other results that might help.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. That's a typically obtuse error message.